# Moving task in MS Outlook by keyboard

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

How to moving up and down tasks in MS Outlook by keyboard in task list view.
Is it possible (I use MS Outlook 2016)?

Answer (score 2):

As I know, there's no such a keyboard to move the task up and down in Outlook client. As a workaround, it's suggested that you could drag the task up and down.

By the way, I noticed that you may want to make your work easier when dealing with tasks, perhaps these task related shortcuts will be helpful, please refer to this article if you need: [Tasks keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#:%7E:text=Top%20of%20Page-,Tasks%20keyboard%20shortcuts,-To%20do%20this).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.